# Deleting users and "Server returned referral"

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am writing a script that searches for AD users with a particular combination of attributes, and deletes them. The entire script works when I use "company.local" for the "-Server" parameter. When I select a 2008R2 DC, instead of deleting the objects, I get the following error:

```
Remove-ADUser : A referral was returned from the server At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-ADUser $user
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (CN=John Doe...mpany,DC=local:ADUser) [Remove-ADUser], ADRefer   ralException    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8235,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADUser
```

What gives? Thanks.

Here is the pertinent code:
Get a DC:

```
Function Get-DomainControllerName {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        $DNSDomainName
    )

    $domainControllers = Get-ADDomainController -Filter * -Server $DNSDomainName

    Foreach ($domainController in $domainControllers) {
        If ($domainController.OperatingSystem -like '*2003*') {
            Write-Warning ("Skipping {0}, because it is not Server 2008 (or higher)." -f $domainController.HostName)
        }
        Else {
            $dc = $domainController.HostName
        }
    }

    Write-Output ("Using {0} to connect to Active Directory." -f $dc) | Out-File -FilePath $outputPath\$OutputFileName -Append
    Return $dc
}
```

Get users:

```
$allDisabledUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties ExtensionAttribute4,msExchUserAccountControl -Server $dc
```

Delete the users:

```
Foreach ($user in $allDisabledUsers) {
    Remove-ADObject $user -Server $dc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using FQDN of the server? ie
`-Server "DOMAINCONTROLLER.domain.local"`

Comment: Yes, it is the FQDN that I'm passing in.

Comment: I would need some more of your code to see what's happening here.

Comment: Okay, I added it to the original post.